# Why isn't my checkbox variables alternating?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a very simple program

```
def prog2300():
    window2300 = tk.Tk()
    window2300.title("COnfig")
    window2300.geometry("600x800")
    window2300.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    window2300.configure(bg='#34aeeb')

    configChA2300           = IntVar()
    configChB2300           = IntVar()

    def chAconfigVis():
        print (configChA2300.get())

    def chBconfigVis():
        print (configChB2300.get())

    CBSingle = Checkbutton(window2300, text="Ch A (Single)", font=("Arial", 12), 
    variable=configChA2300, command = chAconfigVis)
    CBSingle.grid(row=5, sticky=W, padx=10)
    CBSingle.configure(bg='#34aeeb')

    CBDual = Checkbutton(window2300, text="Ch B (Dual)", font=("Arial", 12), 
    variable=configChB2300, command = chBconfigVis)
    CBDual.grid(row=6, sticky=W, padx=10)
    CBDual.configure(bg='#34aeeb')

    ButtonClose= tk.Button(window2300, text="Close", width=15, font=("Arial", 14), 
    command=window2300.destroy)
    ButtonClose.grid(columnspan=1, column = 0, row=7, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)   

prog2300()

main.mainloop()
```

So if I click the CHA box, the variable configChA2300 should go 1.  If I deselect, it should go 0.  But here, it stays on 0.  Same goes for ChB Box.  Can someone please help?

Comment: It is obviously `main` is an instance of `Tk`, so you have two instances of `Tk` which may be the cause of the issue.  Change `window2300` to instance of `Toplevel` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 - ARGH!  I knew I was missing something easy.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where `main` is defined at all.